# process id from window id

Tags: 12.04, window, process

When i run `xprop -id <wid>` on a given windows id for an opengl application (Ubuntu 12.04) i get a bunch of properties, but i don't see `_NET_WM_PID`;

```
$ xprop -id 0x4a00002 
_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY(CARDINAL) = 0, 488, 64, 65
XKLAVIER_STATE(INTEGER) = 0, 0
_NET_WM_FULLSCREEN_MONITORS(CARDINAL) = 4294967295, 1852143205, 19456, 1645412352
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = 
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL) = 1, 1, 28, 1
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "C"
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
        Initial state is Normal State.
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        user specified location: 50, 50
        user specified size: 640 by 480
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "gliese-581h"
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "Full-Screen & Windowed Mode"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Full-Screen & Windowed Mode"
```

how do i access the process pid associated to the window id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's there for windows which support it:

```
$ xprop -id 0x0540019c| grep _NET_WM_PID
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 25685
```

But not all do:

```
$ xprop -id 0x2000006| grep _NET_WM_PID
$
```

As far as I know there is no way to access the PID for such a window.

Comment: fair enough. What is the cause of the difference? the application in question is a freeglut sample. Is there something api-wise that a good linux citizen application needs to do in order to have its PID set? Is there something i can do at application-launch so that the PID is set? like setting the x property by an external process?

Comment: I don't know. From some short tests it seems that all OpenGL windows don't support `_NET_WM_PID`.