# How to know the pid of active window

Tags: window

How to know the pid of active (focused) window?

I want to write a script in which it is necessary to know whether the user is actively  using a program [browsing internet with somthing say firefox] or doing something else [writing text with something say gedit]

In my case i want to download big files but don't want to hurt browsering speed. so when i browse the active window is of firefox and i want to stop downloading. When i read pdf active window is of pdf reader and i want to resume download. That's it.

Comment: close to a duplicate of [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/25644/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I managed to work get the PID of actively focused window with xdotool

```
xprop -id `xdotool getwindowfocus` | grep '_NET_WM_PID' | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]*$'
```

Comment: I take it you got `xprop -id ...` working?

Answer (score 6):

Using xdotool's window stack:

```
xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid
```

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
WINDOW_PID=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid)
...
```

Comment: I don't know y this isn't the accepted answer, but this is the most simple and the best one

Answer (score 4):

`xdpyinfo` has, buried in its voluminous output, the window id of the window with the focus (see: [Which window has the current focus?](https://askubuntu.com/q/25644/)).
With that, you can use `xprop` to get the the associated PID.

```
xprop -id `xdpyinfo | grep -Eo 'window 0x[^,]+' | cut -d" " -f2` | grep PID
```

Comment: Sorry, No output on 10.04

Comment: `xdpyinfo | grep -Eo 'window 0x[^,]+' | cut -d" " -f2`  output **0x3e00122**

Comment: what does `xprop -id 0x3e00122` (or whatever your new current window id is) give you?

Comment: It looks like some windows [don't support _NET_WM_PID](http://askubuntu.com/a/221114/23949), but firefox and evince both seem to

Comment: and in this case you might find useful to take a look at `xprop -id [active window] | grep WM_CLASS`

Comment: `xprop -id xxxxx` not giving anything  on my 10.04 and 12.10. Using `xprop` without -id works O.K (prints currect pid, etc). See Output @ 


http://pastebin.com/rcdE9RrQ

Answer (score 1):

bash

```bsh
xdotool getwindowpid `xdotool getactivewindow`
```

fish

```
xdotool getwindowpid (xdotool getactivewindow)
```

Comment: `xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool getactivewindow)`

Answer (score 0):

The following works with Gnome 43:

1. Install https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4974/window-calls-extended/
2. Run `gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/WindowsExt --method org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.WindowsExt.FocusPID | sed -E "s/\\('(.*)',\\)/\\1/g"` to get the PID of the focussed window or use a different method.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but Google led me here, so in case someone is searching for a `xprop`-only answer:

```bash
xprop -id $(xprop -root '\t$0' _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -f2) '\t$0' _NET_WM_PID | cut -f2
```

NOTE: `'\t$0'` makes `xprop` use TAB as the value separator, the default delimiter for `cut`.

Answer (score -1):

You can install wmctrl then use it to list all windows, `wmctrl -l`.

Comment: This is a bit too brief to be helpful I think. Could you extend your answer to include some steps to take on how to get the *active* window for example? Or how to use the output in scripting, etc.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there, I too am stuck on how to manipulate the output into something useful. Sorry.